# Referring subdomain traffic showing up as direct traffic in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have two sites http://www.beachcomberhottubs.com/ and http://estore.beachcomberhottubs.com/ with two different Analytics codes on them.

I can see from event tracking that people are clicking from the main domain to the subdomain, but there is no referral traffic from the main domain on the subdomain's Analytics. Almost all of the traffic is coming up as direct traffic.

Any idea why this might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think GA is treating the estore site as the same site due to the following command

```
  ga('create', 'UA-47011605-1', 'beachcomberhottubs.com');

  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

giving it the same top level domain as the www site. I think it should be

```
  ga('create', 'UA-47011605-1', 'estore.beachcomberhottubs.com');

  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

to show that it's a different site to www.beachcomberhottubs.com